# Is there anyway to give a Zookeeper node a NULL ACL via python-bindings?

Tags: python, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to create a node using the python bindings that are bundled with the zookeeper distribution ( src/contrib/zkpython/ ). Using zookeeper-3.3.1.

The pydoc for create states that if the ACL is NULL then that node will inherit its parents ACL however setting this parameter to None causes an invalid ACL exception.

I've taken a look at [parse_acls](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/trunk/src/contrib/zkpython/src/c/zookeeper.c#L352) in zookeeper.c and it seems to conflict with the pydoc but I don't have much experience with py c api.

If I can't set this ACL to null is there some other ACL that will cause it to inherit from a parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and found no solution. As workaround you could add an additional step. Example:

```
import zookeeper as zk
parent_path = "/"
stat, acl = zk.get_acl(zoohandle, parent_path)
ret = zk.create(zoohandle, node_path, "", acl, 0)
```

Further tip: In zookeeper-3.3.1 the zk.get() only returns up to 512 bytes of the node data. This should be fixed in the next release (3.3.3).

Comment: I'll check this method out. I'm experimenting with ZOO_CREATOR_ALL_ACL; //(ZOO_PERM_ALL,ZOO_AUTH_IDS). My main concern is if I were to change the password of a digest authed user I want to avoid having to walk all the nodes to update the digest.